# Can I use Sage without OAuth?

Tags: php, sage, sage-one

I want to write an integration with SageOne. It is meant to run behind a PHP application and create invoices when a customer pays for something (they pay 50% upfront and 50% later - I want a Sage invoice created for the second 50%)

Obviously, because this is a customer facing site, I cannot have an OAuth flow here. It just needs to run, as a Server to Service layer. So I really need to create e.g. an API key that will remain active until it's revoked.

Is this possible with SageOne?

Comment: I expect you can use a client ID and secret to authenticate without asking a user for credentials. That's a common OAuth flow. Sometimes perhaps known as a "service account" or maybe a "confidential client". Doesn't the API documentation say anything about it? Give us a link to the documentation of the API you're using, if you're not sure.